# html auto generation is not working in vscode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

**shift + 1 is not working in my vscode to auto populate my html code**

I have tried shift + 1 -> enter,
shift + 1 -> tab
either of them is not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>spacebar</kbd> for auto generation.